# Xamarin Studio не распознает код для Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

**Предыстория:**
После того, как я обновил Xamarin Studio до версии 6, у меня внезапно студия перестала понимать код: почти все было подчеркнуто красным, под всеми using было написано

> "Using directive is unnecessary."

Не понимала студия так любой код, даже новые проекты Android App. Обнаружив такую же проблему только [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726651/xamarin-studio-6-0) и увидев, что никакого решения не нашлось внятного, я последовал примеру вопрошающего и сделал даунгрейд, установив Xamarin Studio 5.10.3. Но это не помогло, Ксамарин все так же не понимает код.

**Сама проблема:**
Xamarin выделяет красным почти все методы, связанные с андроидом. При наведении на любой "using Android." говорит

> "error CS0103: The name 'Android' does not exist in the current context".

Те же вещи он говорит про Activity, Bundle, SetContentView. Пробовал устанавливать почти все версии Xamarin 5.10. Так же полностью удалил и переустановил Android SDK. Ничего не помогает.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.
[image: Проблема]

Answer (score 2):

В общем, я не понял, как у меня получилось все исправить, но расскажу, что я сделал, что все заработало.
Промучившись с этим достаточно времени, я плюнул на Xamarin Studio и установил Visual Studio 2015 с Xamarin SDK. Там тоже начались проблемы. Хоть вижуал студио и понимал, что такое Андроид, но он при попытке собрать приложение стабильно выдавал следующие ошибки:

> aapt.exe завершилась с кодом 1073741819
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Попробовал [обновить JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) до последней версии, как советовали в сети, но изменений не было.
После этого проверил с надеждой Xamarin Studio и удивился тому, что он переставал выдавать старые ошибки, которые я описывал в вопросе. Теперь он выдавал те же ошибки, что и VS2015.
В итоге со сторонней помощью и методом тыка почти случайно выяснилось, что все это происходит из-за наличия **Android SDK Build-tools** версии **24** *(см. изображение)*. После ее удаления подобные баги происходить перестали и приложение снова стало собираться и в Visual Studio, и в Xamarin Studio. Только вот эмуляторы андроида почему-то перестали запускаться... но это уже другая история.

[image: Все из-за нее]